# Java: this points to caller for methods, but to current class for variables. Why?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

So the following code outputs

```
In B m  
In A m  
In B m2  
2
```

Code:

```
class A {
  int y = 1;

  int m() {
    System.out.println("In A m");
    return this.m2();
  }

  int m2() {
    System.out.println("In A m2");
    return y;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  int y = 2;

  int m() {
    System.out.println("In B m");
    return super.m();
  }

  int m2() {
    System.out.println("In B m2");
    return y;
    }
}

class C extends B {
  int y = 3;

  int m() {
    return super.m();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(new C().m());
  }
}
```

This is rather confusing to me.

I understand that B's m2() is the m2 function that gets called. This makes sense because this.m2() refers to the caller's m2, and C's m2 is B's m2.

However, m2 doesn't use C's y variable, it uses B's y variable.

Shouldn't this.y point to C's y ? Why does it use B's y instead?

Comment: `var y` - what language is this?

Comment: @ScaryWombat must be [JEP 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) ;)

Comment: My bad, was messing around with some things. Fixed it

Comment: Prefixing a method call with`this.` has no effect. The behavior you observe stems from the chain of `super.m()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism only works for methods.

Thus: methods get overwritten, fields not so. In other words: if you run a method from B, then y is 2. Meaning: there are actually three different values of y, and your example will make use the B version of y.

Try changing y to be *protected* to change that.

But polymorphism is important here: as the call to m2 in A actually invokes B m2() that finally returns 2.

Comment: What about `this.m2()` being called in A, but ran to that of B?

Answer (score 0):

You are not overriding variable but rather hide it. Overriding, in Java, only works for instance method. In your case, JVM consider them as 3 different variables like they have different names.